# Correct makefile with one master and two slaves

Tags: c, makefile

I was trying to write a makefile for a multithreaded program that has a master process that executes two slave processes. There is a library too (used by master and slaves).

I am not sure how i should compile the library.

But sometimes, modifying one on the files, the makefile command doesn't recompile it (it says has nothing to do with 'all').

I tried writing it like this (Ubuntu):

```
all:executable

executable: slave1 slave 2 executable.o
  gcc -o executable executable.o 

slave1: slave1.o
  gcc -o slave1 slave1.o

slave2: slave2.o
  gcc -o slave2 slave2.o

library.o : library.c
  gcc -c library.c

executable.o: executable.c
  gcc -c executable.c

slave1.o: slave1.c
   gcc -c slave1.c

slave2.o: slave2.c
   gcc -c slave2.c
```

I also tried:

```
all:executable

executable: slave1 slave2
gcc -g -o executable executable.c

slave1:
gcc -g -o slave1 slave1.c library.c-lm

slave2:
gcc -g -o slave2 slave2.c library.c -lm
```

The program structure is so defined:

executable.c,slave1.c,slave2.c,library.c include library.h

executable runs slave1 and slave 2

Comment: Is that exact copy-paste of your code?

Comment: Yes, it is the exact copy-paste of the code

Comment: Note the typo you have`slave 2` and  in `slave2: slave2.0` , that's a zero, not a lowercase `o`. Do you also have any header files - they need to be specified correctly as dependencies as well. You also have a library.c which you compile into library.o, but it isn't used anywhere else. What do you need it for ?

Comment: So you do realize `slave2.0` is something different than `slave2.o` and `slave 2` is something else than `slave2`?

Comment: The 0 insted of o is added by posting the question. I need slave2 in order to used exec(./slave2 [...] in the executable

Comment: You. Have. Space. There.

Comment: @nos I have library.h as well

Comment: @EagleOne Your two different makefiles does wildly different things. For anyone to provide any help you need to tell us which source code  files you have including any header files and how they relate to each other. Which source files do you need to compile and link to produce which executable ?

Comment: May I suggest you read a tutorial about 'make' and Makefiles?

Comment: Three executables are generated: executable, slave1 and slave2. Executable runs slave1 and slave2 during its execution. Executable need executable.c and library.h, and also slave1 and slave2 need their *.c and library.h. Least, library.c need library.h (all .c needs library.h)

Comment: Did you manually type in the question? Because that's the only way that `o` would get converted to a `0`. SO does not run OCR on the code, so these things can't just get converted. Assuming you pasted, instead of manually [re-]typing --- check your source (and maybe change your font in your editor to one that makes the difference more obvious).

Comment: @Olaf did it before posting

Comment: It might not be a good one ...

Comment: @Olaf If it was, i wouldn't have troubles like this ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your makefile is simply wrong. General structure of makefile is as follows:

```
target: prerequisite1 prerequisite2 ...
    commands to make target (most probably using prerequisites)
```

So:

```
all:executable
```

To make `all` target we have to make `executable`. Right.

```
executable: slave1 slave 2 executable.o
  gcc -o executable executable.o
```

From those lines it appears that `executable` depends on `slave1`, `slave`, `2` and `executable.o`. Command below uses only `executable.o` to create `executable`, so there are unnecessary prerequisites (and a typo).

Next:

```
slave1: slave1.o
    gcc -o slave1 slave1.o

slave2: slave2.o
    gcc -o slave2 slave2.o
```

Looks right, until you do not need library.o for building them.

Next:

```
library.o : library.c
    gcc -c library.c
```

Here goes `library.o`, but it is **not used** as prerequisite of any of the targets. So it **won't** be built at all.

```
executable.o: executable.c
    gcc -c executable.c

slave1.o: slave1.c
    gcc -c slave1.c

slave2.o: slave2.c
    gcc -c slave2.c
```

Those looks ok, but gcc commands lacks `-o module.o` section.

So, as you can see, your makefile is wrong on almost every possible level.

Here is makefile that could work. It could be much (**much**) more compact, but I will write it this way for clarity:

```
all: executable slave1 slave2

executable: executable.c
    gcc -g -o executable executable.c

slave1: slave1.c library.c library.h
    gcc -g -o slave1 slave1.c library.c -lm

slave2: slave2.c library.c library.h
    gcc -g -o slave2 slave2.c library.c -lm
```

As you can see it's simple. To make `all` we have to build `executable`, `slave1` and `slave2`. `executable` depends on `executable.c`, and each `slaveX` binary depends on `slaveX.c`, `library.c` and `library.h` source. If any of the source files change `make` will recompile target. Voila.

Comment: Thanks. I know that i could use both $ and @ to make it more compact, but i tried to write every line in order to make it immediately human-readable.

Answer (score 1):

What you're telling us is that:

- slave1.c depends on library.h
- slave2.c depends on library.h
- executable.c depends on library.h
- library.c depends on library.h
- Each source code file needs to be compiled to an object file.

And at a guess:

- you produce the slave1 executable by linking slave1.o and library.o
- you produce the slave2 executable by linking slave2.o and library.o
- you produce the executable executable by linking executable.o and library.o

So let's state those rules, and have the makefile build all executables by default

```
#1. target becomes the default target.
#have it depend on all the executables    
all: slave1 slave2 executable

#state that slave1.c depends on library.h and so on.
slave1.c: library.h
slave2.c: library.h
executable.c: library.h
library.c: library.h

#State that the object file depends on the source file and
#produce the object file by compiling the source code file

slave1.o: slave1.c
     gcc -g -o slave1.o -c slave1.c

slave2.o: slave2.c
     gcc -g -o slave2.o -c slave2.c

executable.o: executable.c
     gcc -g -o executable.o -c executable.c 

library.o: library.c
     gcc -g -o library.o -c library.c 

#state that the executables depends on the object files, and 
#produce each executable by linking those object files

slave1: executable.o library.o
     gcc -o slave1 slave2.o library.o

slave2: library.o slave2.o 
     gcc -o executable slave2.o library.o 

executable: library.o executable.o 
     gcc -o executable executable.o library.o
```

All the indented commmands (the gcc commands) must be exactly one tab character.

- note also that there are numerous ways to shorten and generalize such a Makefile.

such as this (and it can be refined further too)

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -Wall
LIBS=-lm

.PHONY: all
all: slave1 slave2 executable

slave1.c: library.h
slave2.c: library.h
executable.c: library.h
library.c: library.h

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< 

slave1: executable.o library.o
     $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

slave2: library.o slave2.o 
     $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

executable: library.o executable.o 
     $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no rule that requires `library.o`, so `make` believes that you don't need it to build `all`. Curiously, I don't even see a linker command that uses your library, which is certainly not what you intended. So, add all the required prerequisites to all your commands, and update your rule prerequisites accordingly, and you should be fine.

Sidenote: Virtually all problems with make derive directly or indirectly from missing prerequisites. `make` can't do its job right if you leave it in the dark in any way. So, always try to check that all your targets depend on all their required inputs. Header files, are one example. Any header that's missing as a prerequisite in any rule for a file that uses that header, means that you get incomplete rebuilds somewhere down the line. That's why header dependencies are virtually always autogenerated because humans just can't get those dependencies right.